# Append URL query to next post link in custom query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Is there any way to modify the `get_next_posts_link` function so as to add a query to the URL of that link's `href`?

For example, the default function:

```
$customQuery = new WP_Query();
echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next', $max_page );
```

would output an `<a>` tag with the URL `http://example.org/page/2/`.

And the custom function that I am hoping for:

```
$customQuery = new WP_Query();
$queries = array(
   'q1' => 'cats',
   'q2' => 'lasers'
);

echo get_next_posts_link_custom( 'Next', $max_page, $queries );
```

would output an `<a>` tag with the URL `http://example.org/page/2/?q1=cats&q2=lasers`.

Any guidance on how to build this would be much appreciated!

Comment: you could re-create the function, making your own - the code for [get_next_posts_link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2073) is pretty basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep down that function uses `get_pagenum_link()`. This is filterable with the `get_pagenum_link` filter. So you could add and remove that filter that uses a global variable that gets set in your function before the link is retrieved:

```
function wpse_287817_add_query_args( $url ) {
    global $wpse_287817_query_args;

    return add_query_arg( $wpse_287817_query_args, $url );
}
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wpse_287817_add_query_args', 10 );

function wpse_287817_get_next_posts_link( $label = null, $max_page = 0, $query_args = array() ) {
    global $wpse_287817_query_args;

    $wpse_287817_query_args = $query_args;

    $link = get_next_posts_link( $label, $max_page );

    return $link;
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
$query_args = array(
    'q1' => 'cats',
    'q2' => 'lasers',
);

echo wpse_287817_get_next_posts_link( 'Next', $max_page, $query_args );
```

It's pretty messy, because of the need to use a global variable to pass the values to be added to the URL. So if you don't need to actually pass the query args into the function, and can get them from within the filter callback, do that.

For example, if you're are just trying to preserve `$_GET[]` variables that are on the URL, you don't need a custom function or global variable at all, and can just set them in the callback:

```
function wpse_287817_add_query_args( $url ) {
    $query_args = array();

    if ( isset( $_GET['my_var'] ) ) {
        $query_args[] = $_GET['my_var'];
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['my_other_var'] ) ) {
        $query_args[] = $_GET['my_other_var'];
    }

    return add_query_arg( $query_args, $url );
}
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wpse_287817_add_query_args', 10 );
```

Comment: No problem, I just added an alternative solution to my answer that might work better depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the awesome answer. This helped me :D